# Jquery protocol links check

Tags: javascript, jquery, protocols

my website has protocol links that launch my windows desktop app, how to know using pure js or jq if when i press this link the app works or somthing?
I want to be able to know if i didn't work or the app doesn't exist on the client machine i want to show a popup so he can download the app
And of he does have the app i don't want to change anything.

The link looks like this

```
<a href="internet-manager://open/somedata">open my app<\a>
```

Anyway i can do that? Or is there is a plugin for that?

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit hard to handle this and is not same for browsers 
for Firefox use below code

```
try {
    iframe.contentWindow.location.href = "randomprotocolstring://test/";
} catch(e) {
    if (e.name == "NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL")
        window.location = "/download/";
}
```

for opera :

```
iframe.contentWindow.location = "randomprotocolstring://test/";
   window.setTimeout(function () {
       try {
           alert(ifr.contentWindow.location); 
       } catch (e) { window.location = "/download/"; }
   }, 0);
```

Chrome officially sucks with this regard. If a custom protocol handler fails, it does absolutely zip. If the handler works... you guessed it... it does absolutely zip. No way of differentiating between the two, I'm afraid.